# Hide My site menu from Sharepoint 2010 welcome control

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Using jQuery I am able to hide the 'sign in as a different user', 'My Settings' and 'Personalize this page' option in the SharePoint Welcome menu using the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("[text='Sign in as Different User']").remove();
  $("[text='My Settings']").remove();
  $("[text='Personalize this Page']").remove();
});
```

However, I am not able to hide the 'My site' and 'My Profile' option using the same script i.e

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("[text='My Site']").remove();
  $("[text='My Profile']").remove();
});
```

Please, how do I get around this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using JQuery, you can also use CSS:

```
#mp1_0_0_Anchor, #mp1_0_1_Anchor {
    display: none;
}
```